# Javascript: What are factories?

Tags: javascript

I was talking to a friend of mine who has about 9 years of JS experience. He was helping me with a code problem and spoke of closures and also javascript factories. I never heard that term before and was wondering if "factories" is a thing in the javascript community / language? If so, can someone please explain it to me?

I know what closures are, but according to him, "factories" is the next-level-up in learning the language.

Comment: [factory pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript)

Comment: google for "programming factory".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Please refer https://carldanley.com/js-factory-pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) :

> In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational
>   pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating
>   objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that
>   will be created. This is done by creating objects by calling a factory
>   method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child
>   classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by
>   derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor.

From [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) :

> The Factory pattern is another creational pattern concerned with the
>   notion of creating objects. Where it differs from the other patterns
>   in its category is that it doesn't explicitly require us use a
>   constructor. Instead, a Factory can provide a generic interface for
>   creating objects, where we can specify the type of factory object we
>   wish to be created.
>
> Imagine that we have a UI factory where we are asked to create a type
>   of UI component. Rather than creating this component directly using
>   the new operator or via another creational constructor, we ask a
>   Factory object for a new component instead. We inform the Factory what
>   type of object is required (e.g "Button", "Panel") and it instantiates
>   this, returning it to us for use.
>
> This is particularly useful if the object creation process is
>   relatively complex, e.g. if it strongly depends on dynamic factors or
>   application configuration.
>
> Examples of this pattern can be found in UI libraries such as ExtJS
>   where the methods for creating objects or components may be further
>   subclassed.

Example :

```
var Brand = {
    Daihatsu : function(type) {
        this.type = type;
    },
    Honda : function(type) {
        this.type = type;
    },
    Toyota : function(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
};

var Car = {
    factory : function(brand, type) {
        return new Brand[brand](type);
    }
};

var cars = [
    Car.factory('Honda', 'Civic'),
    Car.factory('Toyota', 'AYGO'),
    Car.factory('Daihatsu', 'Consorte'),
    Car.factory('Toyota', 'Carina')
];
```

Comment: I think you're generally discouraged from using `new` with the factory pattern.